# El infinitivo como sustantivo, ¿se debe usar con o sin artículo?

Tags: gramática, verbos, sustantivos, artículos, infinitivo

Cuando usamos el infinitivo de un verbo como sustantivo, ¿es propio usar un articulo o es opcional?

Por ejemplo:

> Nadar es saludable.

vs.

> **El** nadar es saludable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es opcional en el caso del uso del infinitivo como sujeto.

- (El) Beber vino tinto con moderación es bueno para el corazón.

Fuente: https://slllc.ucalgary.ca/AVal/505/AGUsosInfinitivo.html